# Navigation Item

Tags: kunena, navigation

I have created a company website using bootstrap studio. When done, a new request came up to also have a article and forum pages to the site.

I want to go with Joomla since it has articles and Kunena for a forum. I have two questions.

1. Is it possible, if install Joomla as subdomain to have navigation link to point to the homepage or other pages of my domain?
2. Will joomla registered member also have access to Kunena forum? or will they have to register on each?

Thank you

Comment: Hello @Kelvin and welcome to JSE. Your question is not an easy one, and how I understand it, it should be titled "Hybrid site: Integrating Bootstrap HTML and Joomla". That's not an easy topic and there is no a straightforward answer for such integration. You should rethink your question and specify what exactely do you want from Joomla in that equation, because she is so much more than simple 'articles' holder. And BTW, quick answer to both of your questions is YES, but it is so incomplete that I don't want to embarrass myself by posting an official answer.

Comment: BTW, Kunena is extension for Joomla and it cannot exist without Joomla, so user integration between Joomla and Kunena is automatic, because Kunena's users ARE Joomla's users.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of what you explained, you were creating a static HTML website, with some static informations, when it's done then the boss asking you to add more dynamic sections/functions such as article and forum discussion.

If this is correct, then you have some options :

1. If you don't know how to convert your current HTML website to Joomla, you can install joomla under a sub domain then create a link in your static HTML website to article and forum section in your Joomla. You can do this if you don't mind to have different look of article and forum page/section.
2. Learn and study converting HTML to Joomla template. This is the ideal option, but learning curve is relatively steep and you may need some time to accomplish it.
3. Hire joomla developer form freelancer marketplace to convert your HTML website to Joomla. This will need some money to spend, but could be an efficient move.
4. Find a Joomla template that looks similar to your current HTML website (I believe there are lot of bootstrap based Joomla template available out there), drop the HTML website and install Joomla with that template and tell the boss that you've made some improvements ;)

Answer (score 1):

To answer directly your 2 questions:

> 1. Is it possible, if install Joomla as subdomain to have navigation link to point to the homepage or other pages of my domain?

Yes

> 2. Will joomla registered member also have access to Kunena forum? or will they have to register on each?

Yes

Just keep in mind that the Joomla "sub-site" will look different than your main site.
If you want to give the same look, then you will have to re-create the design of your static html site, to a Joomla template, which will be adequate work and it requires a level of experience.

If I was you, I would build the whole website with Joomla.